# Regex expression matching exact keywords anywhere in a file name

Tags: regex, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

How would You negate the following expression?
`^(.(?<!_all_|_team_))*?$`

I am interested in only those files that contain exactly these expressions with underscore anywhere in the file name. I do not have trouble returning only those that do not contain exactly these.

Unfortunately `^(.(?<=_all_|_team_))*?$`  does not work. I need to tackle an ETL step in the PDI - Data Integration tool.

The alphabetic bits of these two expressions do not have to be case-sensitive.

Comment: Can you give an example where it should match and where it should not?

Comment: For example: DailySales_CompanyName_team_20200629.xlsx, DailySales_CompanyName_all_20200629.xlsx - the two keywords do not have to be case-sensitive

Comment: .*(?<=_all_|_team_).* this work?

Comment: Just `_all_|_team_` or `_(?:all|team)_`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - none of these match the entire file name.

Comment: Sure, if you need to match it all, add `.*` on both ends, `.*_(?:all|team)_.*`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - thank You. It has resolved my problem.